# Node application build using jenkins

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins

While doing `bower install`, I'm getting following in `Jenkins` 2.x. Please help.

```
bower javascript-md5#^2.6.0           ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5.git/': SSL connect error
```

Additional error details:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5.git/': SSL connect error
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: Do you get this error when you try to run the command they specify by yourself? 
`git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5.git`

Comment: No I didn't get any error. I get the results without any error. Any suggestions?

Comment: What distro are you running? Can you verify that you have your basic certificate authority certificates installed? 

For Ubuntu, it's `apt-get install ca-certificates`